# My NextJS app isn't building and returing a type error relative to Layout page type, how do I fix?

Tags: routes, next.js, layout

I'm trying to configure the Layout for my NextJS app, and it seems I'm having a problem with the return type of Layout component. Below is my source code:

// src/pages/_app.tsx

```
[import React from 'react';][1]
import '../app/globals.css';
import App, { AppPropsWithLayout } from 'app/page';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store, persistor } from '@redux/store';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { ConfirmProvider } from 'material-ui-confirm';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { getAppData } from '@apis/appApi';
import { setAppData } from '@redux/features/appDataSlice';
import 'react-loading-skeleton/dist/skeleton.css';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID || '1085433653419-r6fptbnccc52h3q0rnhhsi5ge1onectp.apps.googleusercontent.com';

  return (
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={clientId}>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <ConfirmProvider>
              <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                <App Component={Component} pageProps={pageProps} router={router} />
              </QueryClientProvider>
            </ConfirmProvider>
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </React.StrictMode>
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  await getAppData().then((response) => {
    if (response) {
      store.dispatch(setAppData(response));
    }
  });
};
```

//    src/app/page.tsx

```
import { ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { NextComponentType, NextPage, NextPageContext } from 'next';
import RootLayout from './layout';

export type NextPageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
};

export type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextComponentType<NextPageContext, any, any> & NextPageWithLayout;
};

export default function App({ Component, pageProps, router }: AppPropsWithLayout): ReactElement {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page: React.ReactNode) => page);
  return <RootLayout>{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} {...router} />)}</RootLayout>;
}
```

//       src/app/layout.tsx

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import { CustomMeta as Metadata } from '@components/Metadata';

import AppHeader from '@components/AppHeader';
import AppFooter from '@components/AppFooter';
import AppNavbar from '@components/AppNavbar';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }): React.ReactElement {
  const HeaderComponent = styled.div`
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(4, 171, 255), rgb(171, 235, 255));
  `;

  const BodyComponent = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  `;

  const FooterComponent = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  `;

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Metadata />

        <HeaderComponent>
          <AppHeader />
        </HeaderComponent>

        <AppNavbar />

        <BodyComponent>
          <main>{children}</main>
        </BodyComponent>

        <FooterComponent>
          <AppFooter />
        </FooterComponent>

        <ToastContainer
          position="top-right"
          autoClose={5000}
          hideProgressBar={false}
          newestOnTop={false}
          closeOnClick
          rtl={false}
          pauseOnFocusLoss
          draggable
          pauseOnHover
          theme="light"
        />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export const getLayout = (page: React.ReactElement): React.ReactElement => 
   (<RootLayout>{page</RootLayout>);
```

the error message in the console is:

```
.next/types/app/layout.ts:8:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<typeof import("C:/Users/CongThanh/Desktop/Congthanh-project/frontend/ecommerce/src/app/layout"), "metadata" | "default" | "config" | "generateStaticParams" | "revalidate" | ... 6 more ... | "generateMetadata", "">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'getLayout' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '(page: React.ReactElement) => React.ReactElement' is not assignable to type 'never'.

   6 |
   7 | // Check that the entry is a valid entry
>  8 | checkFields<Diff<{
     |             ^
   9 |   default: Function
  10 |   config?: {}
  11 |   generateStaticParams?: Function
- info Linting and checking validity of types ...
```

and here is error when I try to deploy my app to Vercel

```
src/app/layout.tsx
Type error: Layout "src/app/layout.tsx" does not match the required types of a Next.js Layout.
  "getLayout" is not a valid Layout export field.
```

Answer (score 1):

in your src/app/layout.tsx :
there should be only one exported variable for the layout component ( so remove the export of the getLayout function )